# R function to check when df value < than variable

Tags: r, function

I would like to build a function to create a variable called 'Day' which will be defined depending on which 'Dayofweek' the temperature reaches below a certain level. Unfortunately this is my best attempt:

```
df<-data.frame('Dayofweek'=letters[1:7],'Temp'=10:4)
y<- 7
finddaylessthan<- function(x) {
  Day<- match(x$Temp < y)
  return(Day)
}

finddaylessthan(df)
```

I would like this to return 'e' as the temperature reaches below 7 on day 'e'.
ie. The variable 'Day' will = 'e'

Thank you

Comment: One standard approach: `df$Dayofweek[ which( df$Temp < y )[1] ]`. If there is no temp below your threshold (e.g., for y=0), you'll get `NA`.

Comment: That works, thanks very much Frank